# Checking if 3 hours have passed?

Tags: php

I store a cookie like this,

```
SetCookie("last_registration", time(), 525600);
```

I need to check if this cookie value is at least 3 hours old. I'm trying to block frequent registrations, and no I can't just check if the cookie exists.

Comment: Use `SetCookie (" last_registration ", time (), time () + 60 * 60 * 3);` OR `if ($_COOKIES['last_registration'] <= time() + 60 * 60 * 3) die (" Block ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [set the cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), you can also provide a value (which could be the current time or the timestamp from which on the registration is allowed again), you are currently providing the current timestamp but its important to specify an expiration date "from now + x" so it would be

```
<?php
setcookie("last_registration", time(), time() + 525600);
```

and to verify if enough time has passed you would do

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['last_registration']) && ($_COOKIE['last_registration'] < time() - 60*60*3))
  echo 'registration valid again';
```